# form data is not receiving over email in laravel

Tags: laravel, email

When I am sending the data in email then email is not receiving but when I am sending the static contents then the email is receiving.
What I am trying is sending the `email_verification_token` i.e. generated here. Also, it is updated in database but I am not receiving it on mail.

Here is my controller code :

```
public function resendemail(Request $request)
{
  $email = $request->input('email');

  try {

    $data = [
        'email_verification_token' => Str::random(32),
    ];

    $rs = User::where(['email'=> $email])->update($data);

    if($rs){                                         
      \Mail::to($email)->send(new ReVerification($data));
      return redirect()->back()->with('message4', "Please check your email to activate your account");
    }          
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      \Log::error($e->getMessage());
      return back();
  }
}
```

Reverification.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ReVerification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('reverify');
    }
}
```

Reverify.blade.php :

```
<p>To start creating your profile, {{ $data->email_verification_token }}</p>
```

When this page contains `{{ $data->email_verification_token }}` then mail is not receiving but when I remove it mail is receiving.

Please help me ou.

Comment: Anything in your error log?

Comment: No error is showing, it redirects back to the same page.

Comment: I have removed try/cache, it is showing error now i.e.  Trying to get property 'email_verification_token' of non-object (View: F:\XAMPP\htdocs\csrability\resources\views\reverify.blade.php)

Comment: use `{{ $data['email_verification_token'] }}` instead of `{{ $data->email_verification_token }}` this.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array to Mailable. So you need to access it as array in your email template like this:

```
<p>To start creating your profile, {{ $data['email_verification_token'] }}</p>
```